# Check the current number of connections to MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

What is the command to get the number of clients connected to a particular MongoDB server?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

connect to the admin database and run `db.serverStatus()`:

```
> var status = db.serverStatus()
> status.connections
   {"current" : 21, "available" : 15979}
>
```

You can directly get by querying

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

To understand what does MongoDb's `db.serverStatus().connections` response mean, read the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#connections).

> **connections**
>
> > ```
> > "connections" : {
> >    "current" : <num>,
> >    "available" : <num>,
> >    "totalCreated" : NumberLong(<num>)
> > },
> > ```
> >
> > **connections**
> >     A document that reports on the status of the connections. Use these values to assess the current load and capacity requirements of the server.
> >
> > **connections.current**
> >     The number of incoming connections from clients to the database server . This number includes the current shell session. Consider the value of connections.available to add more context to this datum.
> >
> > *The value will include all incoming connections including any shell connections or connections from other servers, such as replica set members or mongos instances.*
> >
> > **connections.available**
> >     The number of unused incoming connections available. Consider this value in combination with the value of connections.current to understand the connection load on the database, and the UNIX ulimit Settings document for more information about system thresholds on available connections.
> >
> > **connections.totalCreated**
> >     Count of all incoming connections created to the server. This number includes connections that have since closed.

Answer (score 85):

**Connection Count by ClientIP, with Total**

We use this to view the number of connections by IPAddress with a total connection count. This was really helpful in debugging an issue... just get there before hit max connections!

*For Mongo Shell:*

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.reduce((accumulator, connection) => { ipaddress = connection.client ? connection.client.split(":")[0] : "Internal"; accumulator[ipaddress] = (accumulator[ipaddress] || 0) + 1; accumulator["TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT"]++; return accumulator; }, { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 })
```

*Formatted:*

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.reduce(
  (accumulator, connection) => {
    ipaddress = connection.client ? connection.client.split(":")[0] : "Internal";
    accumulator[ipaddress] = (accumulator[ipaddress] || 0) + 1;
    accumulator["TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT"]++;
    return accumulator;
  },
  { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 }
)
```

*Example return:*

```
{
    "TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT" : 331,
    "192.168.253.72" : 8,
    "192.168.254.42" : 17,
    "127.0.0.1" : 3,
    "192.168.248.66" : 2,
    "11.178.12.244" : 2,
    "Internal" : 41,
    "3.100.12.33" : 86,
    "11.148.23.34" : 168,
    "81.127.34.11" : 1,
    "84.147.25.17" : 3
}
```

(the 192.x.x.x addresses at Atlas internal monitoring)

"Internal" are internal processes that don't have an external client. You can view a list of these with this:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.filter(connection => !connection.client).map(connection => connection.desc);
```

Comment: Could you please explain the "Internal" IP's meaning in the return list?

Comment: I can't run above example on a mongo atlas instance: `E QUERY    [js] TypeError: db.currentOp(...).inprog is undefined :` using admin user

Comment: @carton.swing I have updated answer with explanation and command to view them.

Comment: @otong what do you get back for just `db.currentOp(true)` ?

Comment: Seems like it's denied by mongodb atlas: 
`{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Using $all for currentOp is disallowed in this atlas tier",
        "code" : 8000,
        "codeName" : "AtlasError"
}`

Comment: Had to change `connection.client` to `connection.client_s`.

Comment: Is  there an easy way to get aggregated results across all databases?

Answer (score 28):

You can just use

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

Also, this function can help you spot the IP addresses connected to your Mongo DB

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(x) { print(x.client) })
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful - thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 24):

`db.serverStatus()` gives no of connections opend and avail but not shows the connections from which client. For more info you can use this command `sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP`. I need it when i did replication and primary node have many client connection greater than secondary.

```
$ sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP
mongod    5733             Al    6u     IPv4 0x08761278       0t0       TCP *:28017 (LISTEN)
mongod    5733             Al    7u     IPv4 0x07c7eb98       0t0       TCP *:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    5733             Al    9u     IPv4 0x08761688       0t0       TCP 192.168.1.103:27017->192.168.1.103:64752 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    5733             Al   12u     IPv4 0x08761a98       0t0       TCP 192.168.1.103:27017->192.168.1.103:64754 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    5733             Al   13u     IPv4 0x095fa748       0t0       TCP 192.168.1.103:27017->192.168.1.103:64770 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    5733             Al   14u     IPv4 0x095f86c8       0t0       TCP 192.168.1.103:27017->192.168.1.103:64775 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod    5733             Al   17u     IPv4 0x08764748       0t0       TCP 192.168.1.103:27017->192.168.1.103:64777 (ESTABLISHED)
```

This shows that I currently have five connections open to the MongoDB port (27017) on my computer. In my case I'm connecting to MongoDB from a Scalatra server, and I'm using the MongoDB Casbah driver, but you'll see the same lsof TCP connections regardless of the client used (as long as they're connecting using TCP/IP).

Comment: This command returns multiple entries for a single connection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42930337/1843751

Comment: I suggest using the -i flag for lsof. Then you only get 1 entry each connection and don't need to grep for TCP. ie `sudo lsof -i | grep mongod`

Answer (score 10):

I tried to see all connections for mongo database by following command.

```
netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep mongo
```

This command can show every tcp connection for mongodb in more detail.

```
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.1:2715              ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod       
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.1:1702              ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod  
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.185:39506           ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod       
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.185:40021           ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod       
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.185:39509           ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod 
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.184:46062           ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod       
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.184:46073           ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod       
tcp        0      0 10.26.2.185:27017           10.26.2.184:46074           ESTABLISHED 1442/./mongod
```

Answer (score 9):

**In OS X, too see the connections directly on the network interface, just do**:

```
$ lsof -n -i4TCP:27017

mongod     2191 inanc    7u  IPv4 0xab6d9f844e21142f  0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod     2191 inanc   33u  IPv4 0xab6d9f84604cd757  0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017->127.0.0.1:56078 (ESTABLISHED)
stores.te 18704 inanc    6u  IPv4 0xab6d9f84604d404f  0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:56078->127.0.0.1:27017 (ESTABLISHED)
```

- No need to use `grep` etc, just use the `lsof`'s arguments.
- Too see the connections on MongoDb's CLI, see @milan's answer (*which I just edited*).

Answer (score 7):

Also some more details on the connections with:
`db.currentOp(true)`

*Taken from: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5085*

Comment: I've read thought all the answers and suddenly -  this is one of the most helpful. The query gives tons of internal details like it should, including connection time, current table, driver version and platform, and even appName if specified

Answer (score 6):

Sorry because this is an old post and currently there is more options than before.

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").aggregate( [
   { $currentOp: { allUsers: true, idleConnections: true, idleSessions: true } }
  ,{$project:{
            "_id":0
           ,client:{$arrayElemAt:[ {$split:["$client",":"]}, 0 ] }
           ,curr_active:{$cond:[{$eq:["$active",true]},1,0]}
           ,curr_inactive:{$cond:[{$eq:["$active",false]},1,0]}
           }
   }
  ,{$match:{client:{$ne: null}}}
  ,{$group:{_id:"$client",curr_active:{$sum:"$curr_active"},curr_inactive:{$sum:"$curr_inactive"},total:{$sum:1}}}
  ,{$sort:{total:-1}}
] )
```

Output example:

```
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.78", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1428, "total" : 1428 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.76", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1428, "total" : 1428 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.73", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1428, "total" : 1428 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.77", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1428, "total" : 1428 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.74", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1428, "total" : 1428 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.75", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1428, "total" : 1428 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.58", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 510, "total" : 510 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.57", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 459, "total" : 459 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.55", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 459, "total" : 459 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.56", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 408, "total" : 408 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.47", "curr_active" : 1, "curr_inactive" : 11, "total" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.48", "curr_active" : 1, "curr_inactive" : 7, "total" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.51", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 8, "total" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.46", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 8, "total" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.52", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 6, "total" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "127.0.0.1", "curr_active" : 1, "curr_inactive" : 0, "total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.3", "curr_active" : 0, "curr_inactive" : 1, "total" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> db.runCommand( { "connPoolStats" : 1 } )

```
{
    "numClientConnections" : 0,
    "numAScopedConnections" : 0,
    "totalInUse" : 0,
    "totalAvailable" : 0,
    "totalCreated" : 0,
    "hosts" : {

    },
    "replicaSets" : {

    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: It is quate interesting, I also receive ZERO values for that request, it isn't what I want :)

`MongoMonitoringController          : { "numClientConnections" : 0 , "numAScopedConnections" : 0 , "totalInUse" : 0 , "totalAvailable" : 0 , "totalCreated" : 0 , "totalRefreshing" : 0 , "pools" : { } , "hosts" : { } , "replicaSets" : { } , "ok" : 1.0}`

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for. The command "returns information regarding the open outgoing connections from the current database instance to other members of the sharded cluster or replica set": https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connPoolStats/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.connPoolStats

Answer (score 2):

Connect to MongoDB using mongo-shell and run following command.

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

e.g:

```
mongo> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 3, "available" : 816, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(1270) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect with your mongodb instance from local system

1. sudo mongo "mongodb://MONGO_HOST_IP:27017" --authenticationDatabase admin

It ll let you know all connected clients and their details

2. > db.currentOp(true)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can check connection status by logging into [Mongo Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) and then navigating to your cluster.

[image]