# Get the number of open connections in mongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

My program requires a large number of connections to be open (Mongo). I get the error :

> Too many connections open, can't open anymore

after 819 connections. I already know we can increase this limit. But that's not what I have in mind. I'm thinking of closing the MongoClient object, and then creating a new one again after 800 connections.

My thinking is that with a new mongoClient object all the connections will be closed and when I start/create it again, the connections will be opened again until 800. 
Thus not giving the error. (Let me know if this approach is totally wrong/ won't give the required results.)

For this I **need to know the number of connections opened ATM.**  Is there any way to get this information using java?

Comment: Why do you have so many open in the first place?  MongoClient already has a connection pool internally.  You should just create one and reuse that.  Are you creating a lot of MongoClients?

Comment: The program I'm using is for research purposes, trying to generate a lot of data and analyze it. Hence so many connections. (I'm using multithreading) I have a few mongo clients.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check the current number of connections to MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975531/check-the-current-number-of-connections-to-mongodb)

Comment: With this you could create a singleton connector https://stackoverflow.com/a/26085824/2093371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get connection information by using the [db.serverStatus()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/#db.serverStatus) command. It has a connections subdocument which contains the total/available connections information.

For more information :

- [Documentation of server status](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/)
- [Details of connections block](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-connections)

Answer (score 1):

**Check the number of MongoDB connections using MongoDB Scala driver:**

> 1. Create a MongoDB client:

```
import org.mongodb.scala._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

// To directly connect to the default server localhost on port 27017
val mongodbClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()

// Use a Connection String
val mongodbClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

// or provide custom MongoClientSettings
val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
    .applyToClusterSettings(b => b.hosts(List(new ServerAddress("localhost")).asJava).
    .build()
val mongodbClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(settings)
```

> 2. Call getNoOfMongodbConnection by passing mongodbClient:

```
val result = getNoOfMongodbConnection(mongodbClient)
```

> 3. Method to get the number of connections(current, available and total)

```
def getNoOfMongodbConnection(mongodbClient: MongoClient) = {

    val adminDatabase = mongodbClient.getDatabase("admin")

    val serverStatus = adminDatabase.runCommand(Document("serverStatus" -> 1)).toFuture()

    Try {
      Await.result(serverStatus, 10 seconds)

    } match {
      case Success(x) => {

        val connection = x.get("connections")
        logger.info("Number of mongodb connection:--> " + connection)
        connection
      }
      case Failure(ex) => {
        logger.error("Got error while getting the number of Mongodb connection:---> " + ex.printStackTrace())
        None
      }
    }
  }
```