# Single MongoClient instance (Singleton) across entire tomcat JVM

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, singleton

I am trying to create a single MongoClient instance across my entire tomcat JVM environment. Multiple webapps will be using the same instance (for the same database) and I want to set it up so that each webapp will use the same instance. The reason I want to have it be a single instance across the entire JVM instead of each webapp is because multiple webapps will be using it.

At a single time there would be 4 tomcat machines up and running so my thinking is that there should be a single MongoClient instance for each machine. My main worry is the overhead for thread/connection creations.

There will be 2 webapps that will be using it and within those webapps, 3 different classes (2 in 1 & 1 in the other) will need access to the instance.

I've taken a look at this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084965/use-a-single-mongoclient-across-a-javaee-web-service) and just need help with the implementation.

In my case, the code would need to look like this for each class

Kerne > Events Class:

```
MongoDBManager mdb = new MongoDBManager();
```

Kernel > Sessions Class:

```
MongoDBManager mdb = new MongoDBManager();
```

SiteManager > SiteAction Class:

```
SiteDeletionManager sdm = new SiteDeletionManager();
```

The MongoDBManager class is that one that handles all of the connections and the SiteDeletionManager just creates a new instance of it in its constructor. In order to simplify it more, I may create another class just to handle the events/sessions in kernel and leave the MongoDBManager as a class to solely handle the connections.

What would be the best way to do this & does anyone have any good documentation for it?

Comment: Why don't you create an MongoClient instance in each application? Different webapps have different class loaders, I don't think you can easily share an instance between them.

Comment: That's what I'm actually doing so far. Kernel has two, one for events and one for sessions and then site-manager has one.

I was just thinking that it might have been better to share an instance.