# how to see open connections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

The last log I see in the mongod process is :

```
[conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:62206 (4 connections now open)
```

When I call mongo stat, I get:

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize   res faults qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:20  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:21  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:22  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:23  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     2|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0  133b    10k    1 23:52:24  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:25  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:26  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:27  
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 160.0M 475.0M 74.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 23:52:28  
.... (omitted)
```

As far as I understand, I have just one connection according to `mongostat`.

**EDIT:**
I looked into the `db.serverStatus().connection`, it s cool and all but not much detail either..

```
/* 0 */
{
    "current" : 5,
    "available" : 999995,
    "totalCreated" : NumberLong(11)
}
```

How can I get more info about this connection? 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258696/get-the-number-of-open-connections-in-mongodb-using-java

Comment: i d like to know a more generic answer, like mongo shell... and not java.

Comment: did you try the command given in the answer db.serverStatus()

Comment: i ll look into it. it looks promising, thanks!