# How to get the number of connections used (and free) to the MongoDB (from a client perspective)?

Tags: mongodb, connection-pooling

I'm posting the question here just to be sure I'm not barking on the wrong tree.

How to get the **number of connections** *used* (and *free*) to the MongoDB, but from a client perspective (eg. Java client), using the 4.x driver?

There are posts regarding using the serverStatus([Get the number of open connections in mongoDB using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258696/get-the-number-of-open-connections-in-mongodb-using-java)), but it presumes having 'admin' access to the MongoDB. Using a 'regular user'(an db user with lower privileges (e.g access to only one database)) cannot run the serverStatus(). But this provides only a view from the server-side (there are *N* connections from IP *x*).

Other posts mentioned how to setup the connection pool size (eg. using the `MongoClients.create​(MongoClientSettings settings)` (see the 4.x API reference (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoClients.html)):

```
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                    username,
                    "admin",
                    password.toCharArray());

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyToClusterSettings(
                        builder -> builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(hostname, portNumber))))
                .credential(credential)
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> builder
                                                                .minSize(connectionPoolMinimumSize)
                                                                .maxSize(connectionPoolMaximumSize))
                .readConcern(readConcern)
                .readPreference(readPreference)
                .writeConcern(writeConcern)
                .build());
```

But none provided means to get the used and available connections the connection pool.

As mentioned by Oleg, using the ConnectionPoolListener would be a way, but that is available only in the 3.x drivers. The ConnectionPoolListener methods are marked as deprecated on 4.x (although it is still mentioned in the JMX Monitoring section (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver-reactive/reference/monitoring/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working:

- created a *custom connection pool listener*, implementing the `com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolListener`...

```
    public class CustomConnectionPoolListener implements ConnectionPoolListener {
        ...
    }
```

- ... and having the stats counters updated on a *store* (accessible later)

```
        @Override
        public void connectionCreated(ConnectionCreatedEvent event) {
            ConnectionPoolStatsPOJO cps = mongoConnectionPoolList.get(connectionPoolAlias);
            cps.incrementConnectionsCreated();
            mongoConnectionPoolList.put(connectionPoolAlias, cps);
        }
```

- attached this *custom connection pool listener* to the MongoClient connection:

```
ConnectionPoolListener customConnPoolListener = new CustomConnectionPoolListener(...); /* added some references in the */
    ...
    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applicationName(applicationName)
                .applyConnectionString(connURI)
                .credential(credential)
                .readConcern(readConcern)
                .readPreference(readPreference)
                .writeConcern(writeConcern)
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> builder
                        .minSize(connectionPoolMinimumSize)
                        .maxSize(connectionPoolMaximumSize)
                        .addConnectionPoolListener(customConnPoolListener)
                )
                .retryWrites(true)
                .retryReads(true)
                .build();
    ...
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    ....
```

- finally, to access the connection pool stats, just have to query out the *store*:

```
        ConnectionPoolStatsPOJO connectionPoolStats = MongoDB_ConnectionPool_Repository.getInstance().getMongoConnectionPoolList().get(connectionPoolAlias);
```

Therefore, thanks to "@D. SM" for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use connection pool monitoring which is described [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/reference/monitoring/) to keep track of connection states, and deduce the counts you are looking for.

I don't know if Java driver exposes the counters you are looking for as public APIs; many drivers don't.

Comment: looks a good way to go! Thanks for pointing this direction.If it works out, Ill come later and mark as the solution.

Comment: the com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolListener methods are, at the 4.0.1, all deprecated, and even when I tried to attach a sample class to the connection, I keep getting a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. I would like to stick with the 4.x version of the driver.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you following published driver documentation and the provided code is not working?

Comment: Precisely. It is throwing "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: . . .<classname>ConnectionPoolListener.connectionPoolOpened" (but I didn't overwritten this method!).

Comment: You may want to create a new question where you reference the documentation, your code and the error message.