# Number of connections to MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb

I checked number of connections to my MongoDB server using `db.serverStatus().connections` and got this result:

```
matrix:PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().connections
{
        "current" : 45,
        "available" : 51155,
        "totalCreated" : NumberLong(1886475)
}
```

However when I tried to check which clients are connected by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32869810/1843751), I got this result:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP | wc -l
5390
```

Which one of the above is correct and why is there a huge difference in the two outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just a problem with the `lsof` output. `lsof` includes the offset of the file in the output: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/how-to-interpret-this-output-of-lsof-command. So there are multiple entries for the same connection in the output. Once I removed that, number of clients from lsof was same as that reported by `db.serverStatus().connections`.