# How to check the status of database and queries which are running on the MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new in MongoDB. I am developing a software by C# and MongoDB. This software will do some actions on large amount of live data. Is there any way that I can see the counts of connections to my database or the queries that are running on DB or monitor the requests that goes to DB in the mean time?

I do not want to profile a specific query. I want to see what is going on the DB.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far,

Comment: I have tried just using system.profile but it seems in MongoDB cloud I do not have access to use system.profile, also I think in system.profile I just can check a specific query not all the queries and their status on the DB. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: if you wish just to see the counts of connections this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975531/check-the-current-number-of-connections-to-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
db.currentOp()
```

ref: [currentOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp)

for profiling you can set the profiling level using

```
db.setProfilingLevel(level, options)
```

ref: [setProfilingLevel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) and [Database Profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)