# MongoDB performance monitoring in Grafana?

Tags: mongodb, performance, jmeter, grafana

Can you monitor the performance of MongoDB in Grafana?

I know there is this plugin https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-mongodb-datasource/ that helps to "visualise the data"... But I'm wondering if there is a way to monitor MongoDB performance during a JMeter load test, for example, the number of connections or the number of rows written/deleted during a test? Visualisation in Grafana would be nice but I'd be happy to start with just seeing the output somewhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try querying the MongoDB as per this article.;
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter

For monitoring connections, you could try something like `db.serverStatus().connections` as per the detail in this thread;
[Check the current number of connections to MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975531/check-the-current-number-of-connections-to-mongodb)

For other queries you can read the documentation here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#mongodb-method-db.collection.count

As for visualising in Grafana, I have only used that app for monitoring the response time info, avg, 95th etc... Not sure how counts and queries would be displayed.

You could possibly output it to the *jmeter.log file* using `log.info()` so that you have a record of the result...